# Java 8 for-loop inconsistency: List of BinaryOperator vs List of Integer

Tags: java, list, for-loop, lambda, java-8

In the following Java 8 code snippet, the intention is to iterate through a list of binary (2-arg) operators / lambda functions. Eclipse generates the error `The method o(int,int) is undefined for the type X`. The error is associated with the loop variable `o`. In case it is relevant, the version of Eclipse is "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers", Mars Release (4.5.0).

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
public class X {
    public void f(List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> op) {
        for (BinaryOperator<Integer> o : op) {
            int x = o(1,2);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the type of op is changed to List, there is no compiler error.

```
public void f(List<Integer> op) {
    for (Integer o : op) {
        int x = o;
    }
}
```

Why does the for-loop work for `List<Integer>` but not for `List<BinaryOperator<Integer>>`, and how should lists of lambda functions be iterated in Java 8?

Comment: Just a note (not strictly-relative to your question): in Java 8, to operate over data collections (and use labda) you use collection framework and not stream framework? I think this reading can be very useful for you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Comment: @PierpaoloCira Thanks - that document looks quite comprehensive. I'm conversant with both stream and collection frameworks, but made a rookie mistake with mixing up pure lambda-function invocations with Java-method invocations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wish to apply the `BinaryOperator`s of your `List` in a loop, you must invoke the `apply` method of that interface for each element of the `List` :

```
public void f(List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> op) {
    for (BinaryOperator<Integer> o : op) {
        int x = o.apply(1,2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran - that was a rookie mistake on my part.